# Left Alignment Within Gmail - IE / Firefox Discrepency

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, gmail

Unfortunately I can't post the sample code here, but I'm trying to debug an issue in which an HTML email that displays perfectly in both Firefox and IE standalone, ends up having its text center aligned after its framed by Gmail, but only in Internet Explorer (ie8)

Has anyone else had a similar experience?  The HTML in question was generated by a business user in MSWord, so is full of the standard junk that you'd expect dealing with generated HTML, which makes debugging particularly heinous.  I'm hoping that someone else might have experienced something similar before I end up re-writing the entire content by hand.

Comment: If you can't post the code, or some semblance of it, none of us will be able to offer much help. That being said, e-mailing MS Word HTML is destined to be problematic- at best.

Answer (score 2):

Without code this is nigh on impossible to sort out, however:

1- Use tables instead of divs in HTML emails (don't ask, just works better)

2- use inline styles as well as attributes (i.e. `<td align="left" style="text-align: left;">`)

3- wrap your content inside a one cell table with that cell aligned left as well.

If none of these work - Post some code ^_^

*note*: Don't use MS Word for emails - even if Outlook 2007 uses it for rendering....

Comment: align="left" fixed this for me with Gmail and IE.